# Resharper Intellisense is not showing local variables

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2017

I use Resharper with Visual Studio 2017. I've noticed in the last couple days that intellisense is no longer showing local variables (which is very annoying).

In the screenshot below, notice the variable "result" is not listed in the intellisense list. Also notice that I have all the little icons for what to show checked-off.

Is this a feature of ReSharper that needs to be turned back on? Is there a setting somewhere that controls this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try unticking "`ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Filters | Persist filter state`" checkbox. There is a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462280) on YouTrack